# Is there a service that can take a feed and produce a daily digest from it?

Tags: rss, digest, atom-feed, aggregators

I run a feed aggregator (http://planetdb2.com/) and I need to aggregate both prolific (many posts a day) and less prolific (one post a day at most) feeds.

Creating a daily digest --  one post summary of the day's posts -- seems like the best solution.

There's a way to create a daily digest just for Twitter feeds via Yahoo Pipes, but it is neither general-purpose nor simple.

Feedburner will email you a daily digest, but it won't create a daily digest feed.

Is there an existing service that can take any feed and produce a daily? How do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Tabbloid](http://www.tabbloid.com/) would do what you need.  This service reads given RSS feeds, combines new items into a PDF and e-mails the pdf to given address on schedule.

Answer (score -1):

Try yahoo pipes.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

Comment: Didn't he say in the question that yahoo pipes is not simle enough ?

Comment: I guess I missed that bit. :-(  That said, I find Yahoo pipes dead simple, I'm curious what else is out there that would make this any easier.